# SQL Server 2019 Machine Learning Service Issues

Tags: sql-server

We're running a SQL Server 2019 instance for our data warehouse, and our data science team is using the Machine Learning Services quite exntensively. Lately we're seeing a lot of error messages like the following:

> Unable to launch runtime for 'R' script for request id:
> C20AF5A9-DB62-4651-8BA7-14F3306E5642. Please check the configuration
> of the 'R' runtime.

There doesn't seem to be any reason for this, the same code will work one time, and then the next time report this error. I've increased the default concurrent users up from 20 to 100, and we're still seeing the issue.

I'm not sure what else could be causing this, I'm not seeing anything in the logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution from MIAOYUXI for your users:

[SQL Server 2019 - Unable to communicate with the runtime for 'R' script for request id:. Please check the requirements of 'R' runtime](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/197971e9-01e2-45c3-bac1-3a2e2dcaf685/sql-server-2019-unable-to-communicate-with-the-runtime-for-r-script-for-request-id-please?forum=sqldatabasemirroring)

Comment: It would be better to have the important points from the external site written into your answer, please.

Comment: This would have just been a comment but I didn't have the reputation to do that. With respect to your comment, please link to me an example of when someone has transcribed another internet community response and provided important points as an answer.